# extract and use a countdown with imacro

Tags: imacros

iMacros for CR v10.1.1, 'Free', CR90/91, macOS

basically am trying to automate a process as efficient as possible

this is the inefficient version

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
WAIT SECONDS=6
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:FNA
WAIT SECONDS=2
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
TAG POS=3 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:FNS
WAIT SECONDS=60
```

updated version

```
VERSION BUILD=1011 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=192.168.1.1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
WAIT SECONDS=5
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 9999
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:0:00:**
WAIT SECONDS=65
URL GOTO=192.168.1.1
WAIT SECONDS=8
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:FN1
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=3 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:FN2
WAIT SECONDS=1000
```

and basically loop it , but the window that this code is doing its job is limited cause of a countdown but that time is given in the same page the code is executed
this is an exemple of the time

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:1:22:05
```

if possible i wanna know how to extract the time and use it in a wait command
THANKS

Comment: [-1] from me on this Qt... Checkpoints: [+1] for clear and descriptive Title. - [+2] for clear and descriptive Qt Content. - [+1] for correct Code Formatting. - [-1] for 2 Typos in "iMacros". - [-3] for FCI not mentioned. (Check my Profile on how to ask Qt's about `iMacros` a bit "correctly"...) - [-1] for URL not mentioned. - [-1] for no Punctuation and no Capitalization. - [-1] for using fake "wanna-wanna" Chicago-Gangsta-Streetta-Langua. - [-1] for not searching the iMacros Forum which contains DOZENS of similar Threads/Qt's... (Most same Low Qlt like this one indeed...) - Tot: +4-8<0.

Comment: new code added (updated)

Comment: Yep, if the Timer is "dynamically" updating itself, a long `!TIMEOUT_STEP`would indeed be the easiest and simplest Implementation to simply "wait" until it becomes "0:00:00", without even needing the `EXTRACT` Mechanism. Good... (You can post (and accept) your own Answer if your edited Script is your "Solution"...)

Comment: added  0:00:** just in case (its now fully workin but i know that a wait command is a lot more resource efficient than a TIMEOUT especially when the time is given )

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "resource efficient", but `!TIMEOUT_STEP` will make sure that `TAG` retries every Second, `WAIT` is not very "precise", I don't remember the "Metrics", but I think it could go up to +/-5 Min Accuracy for 1 Hour, and depends on the Browser / how many Tabs Open / how many Browser Instances Open / what's "happening" on all Open Tabs, etc...

Comment: "resource efficient" as in CPU .... basically i want to  mix both commands first is wait the approximate time or 60 mn as an example and check if the conditions are  met if not ad another wait and loop it (am on mac so imacro is limited to 3 variables ) i think ill try making a user-scripts

Comment: Oh, good...!, we are slowly getting your FCI, => `iMacros for CR v10.1.1, 'Free', CR90/91, macOS`. That Info belongs to your OP when you open a Thread/Qt... - "resource efficient as in CPU", hum..., I'm not "convinced", I would rather think it's the other way around actually, and/or the Diff will probably be stg like 0.2% CPU anyway, I don't "see" why you'd care, "anything" happening in any other Tab(s)/Browser Instance(s) will have more Impact on CPU Usage... - "conditional+wait" are the Keywords to use to search the iMacros Forum, I've posted many times how to implement that Func...

Comment: see thats the thing , am runing this macro on more than 5 browsers and the WAIT command seems to do better than TIMEOUT cz this one is constantly checking (reading) instead of the idle scheduled position of the WAIT command , ill do more research about "conditional+wait" + can i use this on the mac extension version ?

Comment: Alright, I've retracted my [-1] for adding your FCI to your OP... - Oh...!, and I nearly mentioned some "... unless you run that Script in 50+ CR Instances in parallel, then yep, maybe that will make a Diff", ah-ah...!, but Comment Fields are too short on this Forum/Site, not very practical..., + can't include any Formatting/Code in Comments... I would have some Suggs/Advice on "Efficiency" but would be beyond the "Scope" of this Qt about "Timer + Countdown", => you may want to open a parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum where it'll be "easier" to post longer Comments/Posts...

Comment: ... Comments Fields are too short, grrr...!, but yep "conditional+wait" can be implemented in all iMacros Versions/Browsers...